# How would I retrieve the coordinates of my actor subclass in order to place a new actor at the location?

Tags: java, coordinates, greenfoot

```
public void move()
{    
    //if (this.getWorld().getObjects(Marker.class).isEmpty())
    Dog bill = getOneIntersectingObject(Dog.class);
    Marker bone = getOneIntersectingObject(Dog.class);
    if (bone == null); 
    {
        Marker bone= new Marker();
        getWorld().addObject(marker.getX(), marker.getY());
    }
    super.move(1);
}
```

I'm trying to reference the location of my current actor subclass (dog) in order to place a marker(bone) of another subclass at the coordinates it is located at.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Just in case: If you have any additions to your question, please [edit] it instead of posting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the coordinates of the actor by calling `getX()` and `getY()`, as you do it for other actors.

If you like to call methods for the "current" actor, you might like to use `this`, in example `this.getX()`. But it is only *necessary*, if you need to resolve some ambiguity. Commonly you can just call the method.

```
public void move()
{    
    Dog bill = getOneIntersectingObject(Dog.class);
    Marker bone = getOneIntersectingObject(Marker.class);
    if (bone == null)
    {
        Marker marker = new Marker();
        getWorld().addObject(marker, getX(), getY());
    }
    super.move(1);
}
```

Changes necessary as obvious from the shown excerpt:

- The parameter of the second `getOneIntersectingObject()` is `Marker.class`, because you seem to want this.
- No semicolon after the parenthesis of the `if`. *If you don't remove it: This semicolon is an empty statement, so the `if` will have no effect. The block between the braces following it will always be executed.*
- Rename the second `bone` as `marker` to show your intention. (It would "shadow" the "outer" `bone`, additionally, but this is no problem here.)
- Call `addObject()` with the right parameters: the object to place (the new marker), and its coordinates (retrieved by calling `getX()` and `getY()`).